# Multiple @media queries for desktop and mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile, media-queries

Okay, so i have a web and the content of the web is a little complicated, which means i'll need to change the style using `@media` more than 3 times for desktop resolution, which i use is `@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)` , `@media screen and (min-width:750px) and (max-width:1049px)`for desktop and `@media only screen and (max-device-width : 736px)` for iPhones , since iPhones 6+ device width is 736px.

Now my question is i still can't make it works, everytime i open up my web from my phone, it shows the desktop style, NOT the iPhones style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following Code to your `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In addition, you should use media queries like these ones from bootstrap:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```